# How to debug a WebGL error using the Three.js renderer.info object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've created a toy program with new features that I am now integrating into a larger program I'm working on. Currently in their pared-down debug form both programs are displaying `PointClouds` of textures rendered with `ShaderMaterial` and `BufferGeometry`. Right now I'm trying to debug a WebGL error that is now in the big program, but not in the toy:

```
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.
```

I have noticed that despite running the same visualization in both programs there's a discrepancy in the `renderer.info` object they give.

The console for the toy program without the error reads:

```
render: Object
    calls: 1
    faces: 2
    points: 0
    vertices: 6
```

The console for the program with the error reads:

```
render: Object
    calls: 2
    faces: 2
    points: 20
    vertices: 6
```

The two programs should ostensibly be doing the same thing. Could this extra call and extra points be related to the problem? I've looked through the Three.js WebGLRenderer.js script and believe these values are set in an area that deals with the geometries of PointClouds.

In the toy program with no error (top list), no matter how many texture image points I add to the cloud the `points` value for the `renderer.info` object remains zero, the visualization renders correctly, and there are no errors. However, in the other program with the error (second list) the `points` value tracks with the number of points I add to the cloud, the visualization renders correctly, but I get an error message. In neither case have I figured out how to affect the number of `calls`.

Can someone help me understand these things better, and how they may relate to this error message? Thanks!

**Update:**

I've since learned that if I remove the `PointCloud` from the scene in the program with the error, the error goes away and the `renderer.info` object looks like the one from the toy program, but of course the toy still displays the `PointCloud` and no error. I substituted a Cube with new geometry and materials instead of the `PointCloud` and the error message returned, so the error doesn't seem to be specific to the `PointCloud`. Perhaps there's something wrong with the construction of the EffectComposer:

```
var container, renderer;
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var lightComposer, lightCamera, lightLight, lightScene, lightCloud;

function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
        antialias : false,
        alpha : true
    } );
    var ctx = renderer.getContext();
    ctx.disable( ctx.DEPTH_TEST );
    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    lightScene = new THREE.Scene();

    lightCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( SCREEN_WIDTH / - 2, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / - 2, 1, 1000 );
    lightCamera.position.set( 0,0,1000 );
    lightCamera.lookAt( lightScene.position );

    lightLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
    lightLight.position.set( 100,250,0 );
    lightScene.add( lightLight );

    var shaderCopy = THREE.CopyShader;
    var effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass( shaderCopy );
    effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;

    // COMPOSER
    var rtParameters = {
        minFilter : THREE.LinearFilter,
        magFilter : THREE.LinearFilter,
        format: THREE.RGBFormat,
        stencilBuffer: false
    };

    var rtWidth  = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    var rtHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    lightComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( rtWidth, rtHeight, rtParameters ) );
    lightCloud = LightCloudMaker.getCloud( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    lightScene.add( lightCloud );//***If I remove this the error goes away, if I add a plain cube in its place the error returns. Both the PointCloud and Cube are displayed when the error occurs
    var renderLight = new THREE.RenderPass( lightScene, lightCamera );
    lightComposer.addPass( renderLight );
    lightComposer.addPass( effectCopy );

    animate();   
}

function animate() {

     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
     render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.clear(); 
    lightComposer.render();
}
```

**Update 2:**

It appears that I get the error in the big program when there is any visible object in the scene - a `PointCloud`, a `Cube`, even `AxisHelpers`. The moment I remove these visible objects the error goes away. Putting any of these in the toy program is no problem - no error. In both the big and toy programs the objects display just fine; the difference is the presence or absence of the error message.

**Update 3:**

I've discovered that if I comment out the copy shader pass in both programs (`lightComposer.addPass( effectCopy );`), the image no longer renders (as the copy pass is the pass rendered to the screen), but I can still read the `render.info` values for the render passes in both programs. The results are informative. Without the copy pass, both render passes produce the same values for calls, faces, points and vertices. For example here are the values for a simple cube (the same in both programs):

```
render: Object
    calls: 1
    faces: 12
    points: 0
    vertices: 36
```

Now, when I add the copy pass back into both programs, the results differ:

Toy program, performing without error:

```
render: Object
    calls: 1
    faces: 2
    points: 0
    vertices: 6
```

Big program with the error:

```
render: Object
    calls: 2
    faces: 14
    points: 0
    vertices: 42
```

In the big program with the Web GL error, you can see that the `renderer.info` object shows that the buffer now contains the results of the render pass (the cube values) *plus* the results of the copy pass (a mesh). The toy program that is performing without error is showing values for only the copy pass (the mesh). Why are the values being added together in the big program? Like the error says, the read and write buffer are the same, and that is what these values reflect. What's going on here? Thanks for any pokes in the right direction.

**New Info:** I've also discovered while using the console that the error does not show up until the second time through the render function. Perhaps this is informative, or is there usually a delay in receiving errors back from the GPU?

Comment: Maybe show us your shadermaterial code

Comment: @2pha - thanks for taking a look, I added an update. See above. I started to add my ShaderMaterial code until it occurred to me to try the experiment above. Let me know what you think.